# What is the difference between `Option.fold()()` and `Option.map().getOrElse()`?

Tags: scala

The `Option` class has a method named `fold()`. The docs say:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] 

fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B
```

> Returns the result of applying **f** to this scala.Option's value if the scala.Option is nonempty. Otherwise, evaluates expression **ifEmpty**.

The docs continue:

> This is equivalent to **scala.Option map f getOrElse ifEmpty**.

But is this really true?  I've been told that under certain circumstances, with values of certain types, there are differences, but never with a decent explanation.  What exactly are the situations where these two constructions will behave differently and why?

Comment: What differences are you looking for? You can easily find values that are not compiling for fold that are for map just because the type signature for getOrElse only has a lower bound whereas fold needs an exact match. Not sure about values that would actually compile but give you different results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`Option.fold` is safer than `.getOrElse`. You can see the definition for `.fold` below, where both `ifEmpty` and `f` are of type `B`** (introduced only after scala 2.10, probably):

```
  @inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) ifEmpty else f(this.get)
```

which means you will probably not mess up the data types (exception below):

```
scala> val data = Option("massive data").fold(-1) { _ => 1 }
data: Int = 1

// but if I try to return different type in either of ifEmpty or f
// compiler will curse me right at my face   
scala> val data = Option("massive data").fold(-1) { _ => "Let me get caught by compiler" }
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Let me get caught by compiler")
 required: Int
       val data = Option("massive data").fold(-1) { _ => "Let me get caught by compiler" }
                                                     ^
```

**While `getOrElse` is not as safe, unless you provide the type ([supertype `B` in following definition](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html)) manually.**

```
  @inline final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) default else this.get
```

which means you can return a different type from `getOrElse` than what the original value wrapped in `Option[A]` was.

```
scala> val data = Option("massive data").map(_ => 1).getOrElse(List("I'm not integer"))
data: Any = 1

// you have to manually mention the type to getOrElse to restrict, 
// which is not that smart in my opinion
scala> val data = Option("massive data").map(_ => 1).getOrElse[Int](List("I'm not integer"))
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Int
       val data = Option("massive data").map(_ => 1).getOrElse[Int](List("I'm not integer"))
                                                                    ^
```

The interesting thing is you can return `unit` from `getOrElse` or `fold` which can introduce bugs in an application unless you catch it in unit tests.

```
scala> val data = Option("massive data").fold() { _ => 1 }
data: Unit = ()

scala> val data = Option("massive data").map(_ => 1).getOrElse()
data: AnyVal = 1
```

Comment: I'd say you should generally prefer an expected type `val data: Int = Option("massive data").map(_ => 1).getOrElse(List("I'm not integer"))` over a type parameter for `getOrElse`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Right, I can do that as well but I consistently like to omit the types of my method level variables and let the compiler figure those out. But I would really be curious to know the reasoning behind `getOrElse`.

Answer (score 5):

As a counterpoint to @prayagupd's answer, `fold` often invites you to mess up types in a specific way.

The problem is that by Scala's rules, only `ifEmpty` is used to *infer* `B` and then `f` is checked to be suitable. Which means that using `None` or `Nil` as `ifEmpty`, which is quite common, will lead to their singleton types being used as `B` instead of `Option/List[SomeType]`, no matter what `f` returns.

Of course, there are workarounds: specify `B` explicitly, use `Option.empty[SomeType]` or `None: Option[SomeType]` instead of `None`. Or just use pattern-matching.